# Javascript - Getting element

Tags: javascript

```
<div>
   <p>
      <a></a>
   </p>
</div>
```

In the code above, for jQuery, we can use `$('div p a')` to get the `<a>` element, but in javascript, how can we do get `<a>` element like `$('div p a')`?

Updated 2
If I have many `<a>` element and I don't know the index of the specific `<a>` element, I just know this specific `<a>` element is under `<div id="some">`, how can I get the `<a>` element by javascript?

Comment: Why don't you want to use jQuery? Just learning?

Comment: jQuery not works on some page and I can't find the reason, so I am trying to get the <a> element by javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the `div` then get the `a` tag within it [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/vsHCq/)

HTML

```
<div>
   <p>
       <a></a>
   </p>
</div>
<div id="some">
    <a href="#">my a tag</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var elems = document.getElementById('some').getElementsByTagName('a');
alert(elems[0].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some more info, like the IDs of the elements, you can use `document.getElementById('id')`. Otherwise, you can traverse the DOM tree, see this:

- http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/domTree/index.html

You can also use xpath:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

For xpath, take a look at this tutorial (examples part of the tutorial, actually):

- http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp

In your example, the xpath should be: `//div/p/a`, which will select **all** such element trees, if there are more then one.

Comment: It works natively, though you need to consider different browsers - the w3schools example is cross-browser compatible, you can check for more details there. Btw, why don't you use jQuery? That's why it was made for anyway...

Comment: As per the first link I posted, you can use `parentNode` to get the parent of the found `a` element. You can check if it has `nodeType` of `div` and, if so, use `getAttribute('id')` to check whether it's equal to `some` (see this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Methods/getAttributeExample.htm). If not, recursively go up. I would, however, strongly recommend looking into why jQuery doesn't work instead - I think this is just avoiding the issue, not solving it.

Answer (score 0):

See method ’document.getElementsByTagName’

http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp

Using this method. You would first iterate all divs, and on those divs get all paragraphs, and then the same thing for the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is Javascript; I think you meant standard Javascript DOM functions. Also, it is better to use jQuery for this: find out what is wrong, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel. One thing will lead to another. It will be better in the long run to have a concrete library like jQuery backing you. If you really need to use CSS3 selectors like this, use the [Sizzle library](http://sizzlejs.com/). Sizzle was created by the jQuery group for this purpose. (I am not associated with jQuery or Sizzle except for being a satisfied user).

Answer (score 0):

These days we have:

1. [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
2. [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

and both of these can use the CSS selectors in the same way that jQuery does to get the required elements.

```js
var one = document.querySelector('#some span');
document.querySelectorAll('.resultLine')[0].innerHTML = 'We grabbed: "' + one.id + '" with querySelector(\'#some span\')';

var all = document.querySelectorAll('#some span');
var idList = '';
for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) { 
  if (i>0) {
    idList += ', ';    
  }
  idList += '"' + all[i].id + '"'
}
document.querySelectorAll('.resultLine')[1].innerHTML = 'We grabbed: ' + idList + ' with querySelectorAll(\'#some span\')';
```

```css
#result {
  color: red;
  background: black;
  border: red 1px solid;
}
.resultLine {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p id="some">
  <span id="one">1</span>
  <span id="two">2</span>
  <span id="three">3</span>  
</p>
<p id="result">  
  <span class="resultLine"></span>
  <span class="resultLine"></span>
</p>
```